# How do I make the button invisible and visible if certain conditions are met in the data grid view.?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview filled with rows and the first column is a checkbox.

Some rows' checkbox are pre-checked showing that these records are processed.

There's one button in the form and that shall be only enable if you click the checkbox(es) in the grid else not visible if not new checkbox is selected.

The problem is that as I have told that there will be always few textboxes checked.

Comment: Is there an obvious way to know when one of the checkboxes is a "new" one?

Comment: What would be good is: posting some code and give more context to the question. But assuming the `datagridview` is bound to a `datatable`, you could simply refer to that `datatable` and detect changes happening to the underlying data, rather than check the UI component. It's not clear what the real goal is - there may be a better way. The `datatable` also has events you could use to detect changes. Each `datatable` also a state: current/unchanged/changed/added/deleted etc.

Comment: Use the `Tag` property of the prechecked `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell-s` to identify them.

Comment: Could simply just data-bind the button enabled property to the checkbox underlying field

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the conditions you set, it's really easy to control the visibility of a button, which Im sure you know how to. It's just the `BUTTONNAME.visible = true/false`, but if you want to create the conditions on if the check boxes are checked then it would be a little something like this -

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub



    Private Sub Waiter()
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
                If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
                    Button1.Visible = True

                ElseIf CheckBox3.Checked = False Then
                    Button1.Visible = False
                End If

            ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
                Button1.Visible = False
            End If

        ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            Button1.Visible = False
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Waiter()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Obviously this is extremely rough, and it uses a timer, in this case it is `Timer1`. There are other ways, but using this is the best way to go. It really depends on what you're trying to do with your code, like accepting a ToS, or EULA. The possibilities are endless

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DataGridView, you would basically be using the same thing, but you would have to reference the cell or column. You haven't specified what the rows or columns are, but if you know how to reference them, and grab values, then you are set, and just use that same code above.